# PWA lighthouse audit always fails on offline test

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, offline

I have this PWA : [mesmenus](https://mesmenus.netlify.app/) that installs well on desktop and mobile and works offline.
But lighthouse auditing keeps satting that current and start-url pages does not respond with a "200 OK". 
I can't undertsand it as it works ok once installed and offline.
[image]

All the lighthouse auditing is fine except these 2 points.

I bet there is something special to do to make it work while in Chrome and offline but can't find any doc on google about this.

Source code can be found here [github weekmenus](https://github.com/b3b00/weekMenu) It uses svelte js

I've also tried using [workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox) with no luck.

Comment: Shows no PWA errors in lighthouse for me. Have you cleared your cache and uninstalled any previous tests by going here in chrome?: chrome://apps/

Comment: I tried lighthouse on a linux mint box (with chromium) and indeed all is green ! Something must be wrong with my W10 laptop, that does not matter